# Unable to import Vue from vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Trying to demo routing with vue.js and vue-router.js but getting SyntaxError "Cannot use import statement outside a module". I am trying to import vue from correct location. Below is tree print out. Am I not importing vue correctly. Thank you.

Tree print out:

```
.
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── js
│   ├── vue-router.js
│   └── vue.js
└── src
    ├── App.vue
    ├── AppRouter.vue
    ├── ArticlesPage.vue
    └── HomePage.vue
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vue app</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app">
    </div>

  </body>
  <script src="js/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vue-router.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import Vue from "./js/vue"; // errors here
import App from "./src/App";

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render(h) {
    return h(App);
  }
});
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: try `import Vue from 'vue';`

Answer (score 1):

## [codesandbox.io PROJECT](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-silence-k9irf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

---

### Tree

```
.
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── index.html
│   └── favicon.ico
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   └── logo.png
    ├── components
    │   └── HelloWorld.vue
    ├── router
    │   └── index.js
    ├── views
    │   └── Home.vue
    │   └── About.vue
    ├── App.vue
    └── main.js
```

---

### Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

---

### router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: () => import('../views/Home.vue')
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'about',
        component: () => import('../views/About.vue')
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

export default router;
```

---

### App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">HOME</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'about' }">ABOUT</router-link>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>
```

---

### views/Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="home">
        <img width="25%" src="../assets/logo.png">
        <HelloWorld msg="Hello Vue from Home page!"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "../components/HelloWorld";

export default {
    name: "Home",
    components: {
        HelloWorld
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are running on standalone way.
In this case you need add type="module" on script tag.

```
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```